# Facebook publish video stream + PHP

Tags: php, facebook, video

I'm using below code to publish a flv file on Facebook wall.

```
$description=$imgdetails;
$href="http://www.abc.net";
$src="http://www.abc.net/test.flv";

$attachment = array(
 'name' => $name,
 'href' => $href,
 'description' => $description,
 'media' => array(array('type' => 'video',
 'video_src' => "http://www.abc.com/test.flv",
 'preview_img' => 'http://www.abc.com/logo.png',
 'href' => $href)));

$action_links = array( array('text' => 'Visit Us', 'href' => 'http://www.abc.com'));

$attachment = json_encode($attachment);
$action_links = json_encode($action_links);

$target_id = "********";     

 if( $facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message, $attachment, $action_links)) {
   echo "Added on FB Wall";
 }
```

above code successfully post the video on Facebook wall but when i try to play the video nothing happens even video file exist on specified URL. What am doing wrong ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are posting link of video to fb instead of video.

For video upload use video.upload method. This way only link will be uploaded not video.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please provide more details on how to user video.upload method etc etc ? any reference link will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to upload video to facebook using the new **Graph API**: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/

For detailed documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

Comment: I don't want to hard code the values for title and description. i placed two text boxes on form so user can specify these, how i can pass these parameters along with video ?